# Regex to extract number from "ISBN: 9783295359"

Tags: regex

I've got data formatted like this:

`ISBN: 9783295359`

How can I use a regex to isolate only the number 9783295359?
I only need the number, so I need to exclude the "ISBN: ".

Comment: Why would you use RegEx for this?

Comment: What did you so far? Show your code!

Comment: What about `substring()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Answer (score 2):

### Normal Version

Try this RegEx:

```
ISBN:\s*(\d+)
```

The data is stored in the first capture group. To make it slightly safer, add a `$` to the end

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3ug)</kbd>

How it works:

```
ISBN:    # (ISBN:)
\s*      # Optional Whitespace
(\d+)    # Capture Digits
```

---

### Simplest Version

Note that you could get it as short as `(\d+)` (since the only set of digits is the number you want to extract), or slightly safer, `(\d+)$` (to make sure the number appears at the end of the string)

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3um)</kbd>

---

### Safest Version

The safest version would be this:

```
ISBN:\s*(\d{10})$
```

The `{10}` specifies `10` digits, i.e it is equivalent to `\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3vk)</kbd>

---

If you cannot get data from one capture group for whatever reason, or just want shorter code, you can use a Positive Lookbehind to not select the `ISBN:` part. You could need to change the `ISBN:\s*` part to:

```
(?<=ISBN:\s)
```

Note that this will only allow one whitespace between the `:` and ISBN Number. Also, this method only works if you are using *PCRE* (**P**earl **C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpressions). You can also remove the `()` around `\d+`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/mP1aR4/2)</kbd>

Comment: You could also limit the number of digits to 13, just in case.

Comment: @alesc Good idea, I'll update my answer! Thanks! Oh, and there are only `10` digits `;)`

Comment: Not really: _The ISBN is 13 digits long if assigned on or after 1 January 2007, and 10 digits long if assigned before 2007._ From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number).

Comment: @alesc I am not too familiar with ISBN numbers, though I did think it was around 13. However, in the OP's question, it is only 10 digits long. Thanks for the info though!]

Answer (score 0):

You an extract this using simple regex. See PCRE example below.

```
(?<=ISBN:\s)(\d+)
```

This regex will exclude `ISBN:` and just capture numeric part.

See demo at https://regex101.com/r/zK1uM9/1